# pdf file size javascript or html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Is there a way I can get the file size of a PDF without clicking on a button from an input box. Basically I have a row of 5 links to pdf files, and I want to append the filesize of each pdf on to the end of the link:

```
<a href="www.pdf.com/pdf">PDF Name - 4MB</a>
<a href="www.pdf.com/pdf">PDF Name - 4MB</a>
```

Thanks

Richard

Comment: No, it's not possible, JavaScript has no access to FileSystem, you can only get the details of a file through file inputs.

Comment: while you could get the sizes if you were creating the links from a server side activity (most of them do have access to FileSystem to do what you need) JS can't help you there without a user interaction ... unless it's viable to make an ajax call to pre-download the file and get the size of the returned data (though I *really* wouldn't recommend that!)

Answer (score 2):

```
        // File size counter function 
    function readablizeFilesize(bytes) {
    var s = ['bytes', 'kb', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'];
    var e = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes)/Math.log(1024));
    return (bytes/Math.pow(1024, Math.floor(e))).toFixed(2)+" "+s[e];
    }
    var length = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(length))) {
    var fileSize = readablizeFilesize(length);
    var anchor = '<a href="www.pdf.com/pdf">PDF Name - ' + fileSize + '</a>'
    console.log(anchor);

    }
Plese Try with this
```